# (Google's Data Layer) Is there a way to stop variables being overwritten when a new variable with the same name appears?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

We currently send an event similar to this to our customers dataLayer:

event_name{
variable_a : blah_blah
}

We have a problem now. One of our customers uses this exact variable name and heavily depends on it. Our variable overwrites theirs, as it appears later. We can't simply rename our event as this would break all other customer integrations via GTM, which use the variables.

Is there any way around this?

I haven't found any way to store different values from the same variable name, even when the events are different. It seems to be a dead end, unless there is some other function/method I can try.

Comment: JavaScript allows overwriting of variable names, there is no good workaround besides changing the code and using a prefix of some sort. Two variables with the same name cannot exist. How would you access them? Hey also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)